# Paypal API - accepting credit cards outside US

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the Paypal Website Payment Pro API with DirectPay.  Is it possible to accept credit cards from outside the US?  Do I have a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. As A user from outside the US I can perfectly use it. Paypal accepts these creditcards. Usually it is still Mastercard & Visa.

Comment: And have a look at "Supported currencies by product" if you're going to be charging buyers in multiple currencies. Website Payments Pro for US accounts and Website Payments Pro for UK accounts support different currencies https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/240/kw/currencies%20product

Comment: Additionally, some card types such as Maestro are only supported when charged in a GBP currency and with 3D Secure enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'm from Chile, south-america and I use PayPal all the time. There are more fees an comitions, but what are you gonna do.

Comment: This is specifically in regards to Website Payments Pro. Paying with a PayPal account is different, and is supported differently, than Website Payments Pro with the DoDirectPayment API.